# Multiple Auth0 SDKs in the same React app

Tags: auth0

I'm already using the Auth0.js SPA SDK to log my users in. I need to update their profiles on Auth0 and, as far as I understood, this SDK does not support this. I would therefore like to use the auth0.js SDK in the same project, but without asking the user to re-login to get a token for the Management API audience and use it to update their profile.

Any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain Management API token in your SPA. As described here: https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2/get-access-tokens-for-spas#available-scopes-and-endpoints
 Then, you should be able to update the existing user profile by using any HTTP CLIENT  (FETCH API or Request library).

> This means that Management API Tokens for SPAs have certain
>   limitations. Specifically, they are issued in the context of the user
>   who is currently signed in to Auth0 which limits updates to only the
>   logged-in user's data. Although this restricts use of the Management
>   API, it can still be used to perform actions related to updating the
>   logged-in user's user profile.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that. If it means not asking the user to login again even though I’m asking for a token with a different audience, then that would be indeed what I need.